# Test site or ip address availibelity

Tags: android, connection

I have done an android application that read from database located on web server (php,json,...). If the server is off or the ip address not found, the application displays:

> Unfortunately the app has been stopped.

I want to display customized error message instead. example *"Unable to reach the server"* and the app continue working normally.

How to check the server or ip address is reachable or available to avoid the previews message?

Comment: Use try catch to handle exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by this code:

```
public static boolean ping()
{
 System.out.println(" executeCammand");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try
    {
        Process  mIpAddrProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 "+server);
        int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
         if(mExitValue==0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ignore)
    {

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {

    }
    return false;
}
```